# Implementing simple cache in Windows Phone 8.1 Class Library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, async-await, portable-class-library

I am trying to implement a simple caching mechanism in a windows phone 8.1 API that I am creating. I have chosen a Windows Phone Portable Class Library template in visual studio.

Refrence : http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-22-Storing-and-Retrieving-Serialized-Data

The cache class looks something like this,

```
[DataContract]
class cache
{
    private const string JSONFILENAME = "data.json";

    [DataMember]
    Dictionary<Int32, item> cDictionary;

    [DataMember]
    int _maxSize;

    public int MaxSize
    {
      get { return _maxSize; }
      set { _maxSize = value; }
    }
    public cache(int maxSize){
        cDictionary = new Dictionary<int, item>();
        _maxSize = maxSize;
    }
    public void push(Int32 id, item obj)
    {
        if (!cDictionary.ContainsKey(id)) {
            cDictionary.Add(id, obj);
        }            
    }

    internal static async Task<cache> Load()
    {
        cache obj = null;
        try
        {
            var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(cache));

            using (var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(JSONFILENAME))
            {
                obj = (cache)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            obj = null;
        }

        return obj;
    }

    internal static async void Save(cache obj)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(cache));
        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
                      JSONFILENAME,
                      CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        }
    }}
```

The item class whose objects go into the dictionary looks like this,

```
[DataContract]
class item
{
    [DataMember]
    string _fName;

    public string FName
    {
        get { return _fName; }
        set { _fName = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    string _lName;

    public string LName
    {
        get { return _lName; }
        set { _lName = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    int _id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public item(int id, string fName, string lName)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.FName = fName;
        this.LName = lName;
    }
}
```

**The idea is** : The end user creates an instance of the api and calls a method doSomething(). The method first looks in the cache (not shown in the example) if found, returns the Item object back, or else, gets the item object from a web service(not shown) and then push it to cache.

```
public class api
{
    cache tCache;
    string apiKey;

    public laas(string apiKey)
    {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.tCache = new cache(100);
    }

    public async void Initialize(api obj)
    {
        //If cache exists
        obj.tCache = await cache.Load();
        if (obj.tCache == null)
        {
            obj.tCache = new cache(100);
        }
    }

    public void doSomething(string id)
    {            
        tCache.push(id.GetHashCode(),new item(1,"xxxx","xxx"));
        cache.Save(tCache);
    }
}
```

I wanted to initialize/load the cache in the constructor of the api class, but since ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder provide only async methods to read and write data from persistent storage, I created a separate static async class Initiialize() that would load the cache, since making an async constructor makes no sense.

**Problem**: the statement **tCache.push(id.GetHashCode(),new item(1,"xxxx","xxx"));** in the doSomething() throws **null reference exceptions**. This could possibilly be happening because the tCache hasn't been loaded/initialized yet due to the async operation.

I had tried **obj.tCache = await cache.Load().Result** to wait for the loading to complete, but that hangs my application. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Could you please point me in the right directions here? Is my diagnonis right? Is there a better way to do it? Any pointer is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably happening is that you're calling `Initialize` but not awaiting it, because it is `async void`.

What you need to do is change:

```
public async void Initialize(api obj)
```

To:

```
public async Task Initialize(api obj)
```

Then, you'll need to `await Initialize(obj)` which will ensure that caches completion before use.

Note that `async void` is ment only for top level event handlers and shouldn't be used otherwise.
Also, the reason `Task.Result` hangs your application is because it is causing a deadlock, which is related to the way `async` marshals your synchronization context between calls.